# Missing mysqlclient library when installing Sphinx with Homebrew

Tags: mysql, sphinx, macports, homebrew

I am trying to install Sphinx search engine on my Mac 10.8.1.

My MAMP environment is set up using MacPorts. Since Sphinx port is only at 0.9.9, I turn to Homebrew to install the latest stable version 2.0.5.

I ran into a few errors at first, like missing mysql_config (which was solved by making a link to mysql_config5). But now, when I try to install Sphinx, it tells me:

```
library not found for -lmysqlclient
```

But under /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/, I found the following files:

```
libmysqlclient.16.dylib
libmysqlclient.a
libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient.16.dylib
libmysqlclient.la
libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib
libmysqlclient_r.a
libmysqlclient_r.dylib -> libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib
libmysqlclient_r.la
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Milo

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew won't look under the `/opt/local` tree for libraries (neither will most compilers, unless explicitly told to do so). Make sure the MySQL libraries are installed or symlinked under `/usr/local`.

Comment: I did add symbol links in /usr/local, but I still have "library not found for -lmysqlclient" error.